# Problems With Dynamically Resizing UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm attempting to dynamically resize a custom `UITableViewCell` to fit an attributed string's content. This is the result:

[image]

When I initialize my tableView I do the following:

```
self.chatsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 72.0;
self.chatsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

I also implemented the following method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

As you can see it is resizing my height (the smaller allowed is 72). However, for some reason it's creating a weird effect. I'm using storyboard, and auto layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it to the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `estimatedRowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as well.

Answer (score 0):

It should work only with the two properties you set , the row height and the estimated row height.
first try to remove the delegate method.
If the table "Jumps" a little when you scroll (because of a bug) then also implement the two delegate methods, heightForRow and estimatedHeightForRow and return the same values as you set in the properties , estimatedRowHeight = 72 and rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension.
If it's still doesn't work then I would double check the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 8+

1. Set up cell constraints. Make sure that **ALL** subviews that affects cell height are vertical connected. In this case: top edge of top label is pinned to superview's top AND top labels bottom edge is pinned to bottom's label top edge AND bottom's label bottom edge is pinned to superview's bottom. Vertical constraints chain have to be closed. In your case it looks like a bottom edge of bottom label is not pinned to `contentView`s bottom edge.
2. When dequeuing cell for reuse always use
   `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` not a shorter version without `indexpath` specified.
3. Set `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`
4. Set `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0;`. This step is optional but helps table view proper manage things like scroll indicators etc.

Will work :)